# sqlplus startup - failure in processing system parameters

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am trying to do the startup command

This is what I have done:

```
set oracle_sid=ORCL
sqlplus /nolog
SQL> conn /as sysdba
startup
```

It shows this error message:

> failure in processing system parameters
>   could not open parameter file "C:\Program\11.2.0\DBhome_1\Database\initorcl.ora"

I checked and found out that "initoracl.ora" doesn't exist inside this path:

```
C:\Program\11.2.0\DBhome_1\Database
```

I found a init.ora file in:

```
C:\Program\11.2.0\dbhome_1\dbs
```

I tried doing this command:

```
startup pfile="C:\Program\11.2.0\dbhome_1\dbs\init.ora"
```

It shows this error:

> invalid value given for the diagnostic_dest init.ora parameter
>   the specified ADR Base Directory does not existed [C:\program\11.2.0\dbhome_1\database\]
>   specific directory does not exist
>   additional error information
>    the filename, directory name, or volume syntax is incorrect.

What should I do?

Comment: How was the database created? Has it started before? Does the `initorcl.ora` exist somewhere else, or do you have a valid `spfile`?

Comment: I checked. there's no initorcl.ora or spfile. I am really sure how to create a database or whether a database is created as I am using this software the first time. where do I get this initorcl.ora file from?

Comment: What is %ORACLE_HOME% set to? Is your database definitely called `ORCL`? Are you certain a database has even been created?

Answer (score 1):

You can manually create the `init.ora` file. Only two parameters are required - `db_name` and `db_block_size`.

Then run:

```
startup pfile='c:\program\11.2.0\dbhome_1\dbs\init.ora'
```

If you have a valid spfile then run:

```
create pfile from spfile
```

You should be able to startup your database.

Comment: Apperently the OP has no spfile. But even if he has one, why should he create a pfile? And why should he configure the init.ora file of the dbs directory to startup the database? All in all I think the user will not have much fun with Oracle software if he does not create a database.

Answer (score 1):

Set the ORACLE_SID  and ORACLE_HOME  variables properly.  They must be in upper case letters.

Second, share the content of directory. ORACLE_HOME/dbs

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 way to solve the problem.

One way is that,
there might be another *.ora file (e.g spfileyourdbname.ora).
If there is, just do the same thing as you did:

```
    SQL> startup pfile = 'C:\Program\11.2.0\dbhome_1\dbs\spfileyourdbname.ora'
```

Or 
Another way is,
just copy the below codes, change the relevant directories and parameters, and  save in the required directory (e.g $ORACLE_HOME/dbs/) as 'spfileyourdbname.ora'. Then just do the same thing:

```
    SQL> startup pfile = 'C:\Program\11.2.0\dbhome_1\dbs\spfileyourdbname.ora'
```

*'mydb' is the name of your database [SID].*

Codes to copy:

```
    mydb.__data_transfer_cache_size=0
    mydb.__db_cache_size=255852544
    mydb.__java_pool_size=12582912
    mydb.__large_pool_size=8388608
    mydb.__oracle_base='/home/yeyintkoko/app/oracle'#ORACLE_BASE set from environment
    mydb.__pga_aggregate_target=180355072
    mydb.__sga_target=536870912
    mydb.__shared_io_pool_size=20971520
    mydb.__shared_pool_size=226492416
    mydb.__streams_pool_size=0
    *.audit_file_dest='/home/yeyintkoko/app/oracle/admin/mydb/adump'
    *.audit_trail='db'
    *.compatible='12.1.0.0.0'
    *.control_files='/home/yeyintkoko/app/oracle/oradata/mydb/control01.ctl','/home/yeyintkoko/app/oracle/fast_recovery_area/mydb/control02.ctl'
    *.db_block_size=8192
    *.db_domain=''
    *.db_name='mydb'
    *.db_recovery_file_dest='/home/yeyintkoko/app/oracle/fast_recovery_area'
    *.db_recovery_file_dest_size=4800m
    *.diagnostic_dest='/home/yeyintkoko/app/oracle'
    *.dispatchers='(PROTOCOL=TCP) (SERVICE=mydbXDB)'
    *.enable_pluggable_database=true
    *.log_archive_format='%t_%s_%r.dbf'
    *.open_cursors=300
    *.pga_aggregate_target=170m
    *.processes=300
    *.remote_login_passwordfile='EXCLUSIVE'
    *.sga_target=510m
    *.undo_tablespace='UNDOTBS1'
```